# comparing when a page has been modified and current date

Tags: php

I have added getlastmod function to my header and all pages display when they were last modified. Now I would like to add either text or a small new icon to each page link on the header's nav container if the page has been modified within the last 7 days, otherwise show nothing. my logic is this: (i'm not a programmer btw)

```
<?PHP
$date_modified = filemdate;
$current_date = date(Y,m,d);
$new = '/images/new.gif';

if {(current_date > date_modified + 7days);

echo "";

else {
echo $new;
}}
?>
```

// with $new being added to each nav item such as home(index.php), news(news.php), links(links.php) on the header.php's navigation 
// container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little snippet should do it:

```
// get timestamp of last modification
$last_modified = filemtime($filename);
// get timestamp of seven days ago
$seven_days_ago = strtotime('-7 days');

// perform the comparison
if ($last_modified >= $seven_days_ago) {
    echo '/images/new.gif';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jack, I appreciate the snippet, I will give it a go. Your code helped me understand Chandresh_cool's response as well. This is my first visit here so I am a little disoriented. My apologies if I haven't followed protocol.

Comment: @user2300615 That's okay, we all have to start somewhere :)

Comment: I was able to get your code to work after a bit of trial and error, but, this is not a one size fits all fix. I need to output the results of the comparison to a variable I will be able to use anywhere in my code.

Answer (score 2):

filemdate is wrong function

you should use

```
filemtime($filename)
```

and then use this to compare the file time.